# Is there any way to count matches between 2 tables using sql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Ok... I need to do this simple task... I can do it with java or python in a simple way...
But is there any way to do this using sql and delagating the job to the database engine and not to jvm or python?

I have table 1 and table 2

for example

table 1 has 2 stored titles...

"love is a feeling", "harry potter"

table 2 has 3 stored titles...

"abc", "physics 1", "the trip"

Some are different, but some might be coincidential...

I need to compare each entry of table 2 with all the rows returned from a select title from table1...

so it would be like this

it compares "love is a feeling" with "abc" and "physics 1" and "the trip", if findes a match it increases the count...

it should do that with all the names and in the end I want to know how many coincidences I have...

as I say it can be done with java or any lang by querying:

```
results = rows returned by using "select title from table1";
while results.next () {
 results2 = rows returned by using "select title from table2";

 while results2.next(){
    if current results == current results2
        count++;    
  }
}

print count
```

But thats not what I need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.title = table2.title
```

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 4):

try joining both tables,

```
SELECT  a.title, COUNT(b.title) totalMatch
FROM    table1 a
            LEFT JOIN table2 b
                On a.title = b.title
GROUP BY a.Title
```

by using `LEFT JOIN` it will display `0` if it has no match.

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c82a/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.title = table2.title
```